# Feedback from ICommand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an `ICommand` implementation which is stand-alone. It modifies information on an entity. The same entity is bound to a `View`, as a property of the View's `ViewModel`.

What I want to achieve is, the entity (and hence the ViewModel, hence - the View) to update with the new information, after the command is executed. The way I understand it, `ICommand`-s are one-way street. They modify the underlying data, but are not supposed to give a direct result.

So I have achieved this by sending a `Message` from within the Command at the end of its execution, by using the MVVMLight framework. The View Model which exposes the entity also subscribes to the same message and updates itself, when the message is received (updated info is passed as property of the message).

The added benefit is that other View Models can also subscribe and react to the same event. What 'smells' about it, though, is that the backbone of this implementation is `events`. From what I've read, the whole concept of events doesn't fit well within the MVVM pattern. Or cross-VM communication is OK to be done this way?

Example:

**Domain Model**

- User

  - `First Name`
  - `Last Name`
  - `Full Name { get { return First Name + Last Name } }`

**View Model**

- User View Model - wraps around the `User Domain Model`, **but doesn't store an instance of it**

  - `string First Name`
  - `string Last Name`
  - `string Full Name` (Note: Doesn't know anything about how it's calculated)
  - `ICommand Change First Name`
  - *Method*: `MapFromDomainModel(UserDomainModel)`. Invoked when the View Model receives `UserDomainChanged` message.

**Command**

- `Change First Name : ICommand`

  - Changes the `First Name` in the `User Domain Model`
  - Sends a `UserDomainChanged(UserDomainModel)` message

See, in this example the View Model doesn't know how `Full Name` is calculated and doesn't/shouldn't know that when `First Name` is changed, the `Full Name` should be changed too. That's why the Command is working directly on the Domain Model and triggers the Message.

Also, I may have other Views on in the Window, which have View Models bound to the same User Domain Model. By subscribing to the same message they can update themselves independently.

Is this a good approach? Is there a better one?

Comment: I would say that this approach is totally fine. unless you want to add a reference to the viewmodel to your command or to implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on your entity.

Comment: I usually modify some properties in my commands, and then the view updates due to  NotifyPropertyChanges and the respective Bindings. Would that be enough or you have a more complex scenario?

Comment: @heltonbiker, so your command is modifying the View Model, not the underlying data model? The command I execute performs persisted change - against the domain model and because of the executed business logic, other properties of the View Model might change without the knowledge of the Command or View Model.

Comment: @heltonbiker, I have updated the question with a more detailed example. Hopefully it illustrates why the command works on the Domain Model and not on the View Model. Do you think it makes sense?

Comment: Well, the command might act anywhere it is interesting to act, be it properties in Model or in ViewModel. The important thing to update the view is that, eventually one of those actions end up with a PropertyChanged event updating a DataBound property.

Comment: The thing is, the View Model doesn't know which properties it should update after the operation is done. So I needed a mechanism which passes the updated Domain Model to the View Model and it remaps it to its properties again, triggering PropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The way I understand it, ICommand-s are one-way street. They modify the underlying data, but are not supposed to give a direct result.

You are correct. The Execute method of the ICommand interface has a return type of void meaning it doesn't return any kind of value or result to the caller of the command.

> Or cross-VM communication is OK to be done this way?

Yes. The big difference between between using an event aggregator or a messenger to communicate between two objects and using an ordinary event is coupling. When you subscribe to an ordinary event you create a tight coupling between the publisher and the subscriber of the event. The subscriber requires a strong reference to the publisher in order to be able to subscribe to the event and the publisher requires a reference to the subscriber via the event handler delegate to be able to publish the event. This leads to tight coupling between the components which in turn tends to lead to less maintainable applications.

By introducing an event aggregator in between the publishers and subscribers, you can remove this tight coupling. The subscriber observes the event aggregator instead of the publisher and the publisher knows only about the event aggregator and not about the subscribers. Please refer to the following blog post if you want the broad picture: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/

> Is this a good approach? Is there a better one?

Yes. Using an event aggregator/messenger to communicate between components in a loosely coupled way is generally a good approach. Another option is to use a shared service. This is simply a class that provides functionality to several components in a decoupled way. It should implement an interface and you typically register it as a singleton in your IoC container: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22907a0f-d805-4195-8272-7c284b72d2ee/example-of-using-shared-services-prism?forum=wpf

Note that in this particular example you could probably also have bound the FirstName property of the view model to a target property in the view and raised the PropertyChanged event for the FullName property whenever you wanted the view to refresh instead of invoking a command but I guess you have your reasons for invoking a command and then publishing a message to the outside world using an event aggregator or a messenger is perfectly fine.